# What are the options for 'Date.toLocaleString()'?

Tags: javascript

According to the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString) for `Date.toLocaleString()`, the second parameter is an `options` parameter:

```js
toLocaleString(locales, options)
```

Which they use in an example:

```js
let date = new Date(Date.UTC(2012, 11, 20, 3, 0, 0));

// Request a weekday along with a long date
let options = { weekday: 'long', year: 'numeric', month: 'long', day: 'numeric' };

console.log(date.toLocaleString('de-DE', options));
```

My question is, what are the possible properties for the `options` parameter?

Comment: From https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/numbers-and-dates.html#sec-date.prototype.tolocalestring: "The meaning of the optional parameters to this method are defined in the ECMA-402 specification; implementations that do not include ECMA-402 support must not use those parameter positions for anything else."

Answer (score 17):

It's the same as those for the [`Intl.DateTimeFormat()` constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat/DateTimeFormat), whose [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat/DateTimeFormat#parameters) provides a list of each valid property and an explanation.

The possible properties are as follows:

- `dateStyle`
- `timeStyle`
- `calendar`
- `dayPeriod`
- `numberingSystem`
- `localeMatcher`
- `timeZone`
- `hour12`
- `hourCycle`
- `formatMatcher`
- `weekday`
- `era`
- `year`
- `month`
- `day`
- `hour`
- `minute`
- `second`
- `fractionalSecondDigits`
- `timeZoneName`

See the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat/DateTimeFormat#parameters) for the possible values of each property and the behavior.

Comment: Hi @Spectric, why im no able to found documentation about these options > style and currency... that i already used in toLocaleString method... :( there are some updated documentation for this? thank you in advance.

Comment: @JuanRuizdeCastilla `Date.toLocaleString`'s options do not include a `style` property. You might be getting it mixed up with `Number.toLocaleString`

Answer (score 0):

```
interface DateTimeFormatOptions {
    formatMatcher?: "basic" | "best fit" | "best fit" | undefined;
    dateStyle?: "full" | "long" | "medium" | "short" | undefined;
    timeStyle?: "full" | "long" | "medium" | "short" | undefined;
    dayPeriod?: "narrow" | "short" | "long" | undefined;
    fractionalSecondDigits?: 1 | 2 | 3 | undefined;
}
```